# Import OPML subscriptions (file) to Google Reader manually

Tags: python, api, file-upload, google-reader, opml

I have a huge (5,000+ feeds) OPML file which freezes and crashes my browser when I try uploading it to my Google Reader account using the following instructions:

> 1. Login to Google Reader
> 2. Click Your Subscription
> 3. Click the More Actions dropdown
> 4. Select Import
> 5. Browse for your OPML file
> 6. Click Open
> 7. Click Upload
> 8. You will see the following displayed until it is done: Your
>      subscriptions are being imported...

I've looked into using: http://code.google.com/p/pyrfeed/wiki/GoogleReaderAPI
 
But, it seems more like an ATOM/RSS reader and framework as it states, instead of a library to do what I need. I am open to suggestions and methods to accomplish this via HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer on Superuser on [How to import an OPML file with 1500 feeds into Google Reader](https://superuser.com/questions/18044/how-to-import-an-opml-file-with-1500-feeds-into-google-reader)